# How to get "Date and Time" input from a html form and save into MySQL db using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring, spring-boot

What I want to do:
The user will enter a date and time through a html form and those values will be saved to a MySQL database.

createPost.html

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/createPost}" th:object="${post}" method="POST">      

        <p>Description: <input type="text" th:field="*{text}" /> </p>
        <!-- 
        <p>Time: <input type="datetime-local" th:field="*{dateTime}" /> </p>
         -->
        <p>date: <input type="date" th:field="*{date}" /></p>
        <p>time: <input type="time" th:field="*{time}" /></p>
        <p><input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" /> </p>


    </form>
```

Post.java

```
@Entity
public class Post { 

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;    
private String user;
private String text;
/*
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
private LocalDateTime dateTime;
*/


private java.sql.Date date;
private LocalTime time;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.util.Date myDate;  
//getters ans setters

}
```

PostController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createPost", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String createPost(@ModelAttribute Post post){
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String currentUser = authentication.getName();
    post.setUser(currentUser);
    postRepository.save(post);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Currently i m getting this error :

**"Invalid property 'date' of bean class [com.example.demo.Post]: Bean property 'date' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?"**

I have tried many different things but I can't get anything to work. 
What's the recommended way of getting user date and time input and saving it to a database?

**EDIT:**

> You can only bind Model Objects which can be defined with simple types. when the object serialized from the client side to the server , It has no knowledge about the complex types(like java.time.LocalDate) unless they are expressed interms of simple types.

I solved this now by writing a function that translates Strings to sql.Date

```
public Date getDateFromString(String dateString){
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.util.Date parsed = null;
    try {
        parsed = format.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Date date = new Date(parsed.getTime());
    return date;
}
```

And changed the PostController.java to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createPost", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String createPost(@ModelAttribute Post post, String date){
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String currentUser = authentication.getName();      
    post.setUser(currentUser);      

    Utilities utilities = new Utilities();              
    post.setDate(utilities.getDateFromString(post.getDatestring()));

    postRepository.save(post);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Ugly but at least it works, if someone has a better solution please tell

Comment: What version of hibernate are you using? for which date type are you getting the error? there are three date/time fields in you model class

Comment: Considering that the error complains abouto getters and setters of property `date` in `Post`, I think it's relevant to post the getters and setters of that class.

Comment: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}. java.sql.Date (for getters/setters as well) for the current error but I have tried Timestamp and LocalDate as well but I can't get any of them to work

Comment: Can you post the actual code of your getters and setters, especially from the `date` field.

Comment: public java.sql.Date getDate(){
  return date;
 }
 
 public void setDate(java.sql.Date date){
  this.date = date;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Well, what happens behind the screens is that your browser sends both the date and the time as strings, for example `2018-01-05` and `13:37`. Then Spring has to convert these someway to `java.sql.Date` and `java.time.LocalTime`.

Normally Spring has [a formatter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/datetime/DateFormatter.html) for `java.util.Date`, but not for `java.sql.Date` as far as I know. But for some reason it seems to work fine for `java.sql.Date` if I test it.

Nonetheless, there is no existing formatter for `java.time.LocalTime`,  so you have to write your own converter. This can be done by implementing `Formatter`, for example:

```
@Component
public class LocalTimeFormatter implements Formatter<LocalTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalTime parse(String s, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        try {
            return LocalTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", locale));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
            throw new ParseException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getErrorIndex());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String print(LocalTime localTime, Locale locale) {
        return localTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", locale));
    }
}
```

The exception you get though, indicates that you had a mismatch in getter/setter types, so I assume that you have a conflicting getter/setter somewhere that's using a different type than the type used by the `date` field. But the code you're showing should work fine, so I have no idea where that comes from.